# How to write Regex expressions in LATEX

Tags: specials

I am writing a paper that has Regex expressions

> used regular expression “(?<=|)\d*/\d*/\d*” to find report dates.

I tried using backspash before each char in the regex expression but does not work

I tried wrap the regex with $$ but still does not work

how to do it?

Comment: I would use the listings package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex uses a lot of different characters so it is hard to properly enter it. If you could find a character that you were not using, then you could use `\verb` which works so that you pick a deliminator then put the code between it. So if you did not need the pipe character then you could do `\verb|[0-9A-Fa-F]|` and it would just show `[0-9A-Fa-f]`. But as seen in your example, the pipe character is used a lot so you would have to pick something else. Perhaps an exclamation mark. So then `\verb!(?<=|)\d*/\d*/\d*!` would show up as `(?<=|)\d*/\d*/\d*`. You would have to figure out what works for each case.

As the commenter mentioned, there is also a package called listings which is more robust but does not work super well for inline code like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `biblatex` anyway, you may as well use its `\regexp{}` command as an out-of-the-box solution.

From the [biblatex docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

> Perl escape sequences like \t for a tab, \n for a newline, \A for the start of a string or \d for a digit can be used, without TEX trying to execute them as commands, as can be special characters like ^, _ or {..} and #. Only the % must be protected: to match a single % in the bib, use % in the regular expression, a % is matched by \%.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, which was about printing regular expressions, rather than using them for processing bibliography items.

Comment: The command is used by biblatex "to protect a regular expression from being interpreted by TeX" and I have used in the same way that the OP is asking for. I don't know if this answers the question but to the best of my knowledge it is a viable answer to the question.